# Best icon to represent transparency?

Tags: image, icons

What would be the best image/icon to represent transparency?
It should be as compact as possible and fit in a 13x11 area.

---

I see that I should add more information.
I need this image/icon to be placed on a system button on the Windows OS:
[image: Aero][image: Basic][image: XP][image: Classic]... So I'd rather have something more scalable.
One thing to note... This should be system interface, not my program's so it must be as least symbolic as possible and most straight-forward to the idea/function.

---

After igor's idea, here are my results:
[image: Aero][image: Basic][image: XP][image: Classic]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Why not [this](http://www.iconfinder.com/icondetails/26531/16/layer_transparent_icon) [image]?

Comment: I thought about that one too (from Paint.NET), but I'd like something that represents "variable transparency".

Comment: @Vercas try transparent linear gradient to any icon would you like to show variability.

Comment: You just gave me the best idea!

Comment: @Vercas welcome

Comment: And now I've finished my icons. I'm adding them to the question!

Comment: @Vercas awesome!

Answer (score 3):

maybe an [empty glass](http://www.iconfinder.com/icondetails/46052/16/empty_glass_icon)
[image]

Comment: This was totally unexpected... I think it might work but it just doesn't theme with the OS... Windows in this case.

Comment: CorelDraw  and CorelPhotoPaint use this, and for a variable transparency, a glass, plus a line-with-arrowhead. Worked great for them.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a gradient if it's for variable transparency.

A square from black to clear.

Comment: "square from black to clear" - could you explain that to me?

Comment: A small square that is black, but has an alpha gradient from left to right.  So, the alpha would be 1 on the left and 0 on the right.