# Adjust transparency on layers

Tags: map-ui, sliders

I have a web mapping application where we have a layer list, allowing the end-user to turn layers on and off.

We would like to add the functionality for the user to be able to adjust the transparency on each of the layers.

I was looking at Igor's [answer](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/2945/1679) on this Q, and was trying to think on how to incorporate that icon into a slider, whilst making best use of screen real estate.

Here is the current Layer List design:
- Bear in mind that the user controls what layers are in here, so the layer names could be longer
- The arrow is a clickable icon to make that layer selectable or not.
[image]

Looking for some good ideas on how to allow the user to set transparency on each of the layers.

Comment: Seems that PhotoShop would be a good one to copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To piggyback on @DAO1's comment, I concur that cribbing Adobe's layer tranparency approach might be a good idea.  In this case, given that you already have up to four visual elements to that left of the labels: 
[image] it makes sense to *avoid* using the same spot for another inline control.

Adobe pulls out their Opacity drop-down to a permanent location at the head of the list, and makes it context-aware:

[image]

This allows you to avoid stuffing another control in the already-packed left-of-label area.  You may also be able to compact this a little but removing the "Opacity" label and using an icon instead:

[image]

Another possibility, cribbed from Adobe (as usual), is to vertically align all of the controls (and potentially icons) into columns, confining the indentation to it's own column:

[image]

This makes the list of controls easier to scan and navigate than one that jogs left and right depending on the hierarchy. If you did choose to add another *inline* control (say, per @JOG's answer), this might mitigate the concern of additional clutter.

Answer (score 0):

If setting the transparency is the only (or main) functionality the user can control other than move around the layers, then consider putting a text input or [number input](http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html#type-number) (HTML5) in the same row.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the transparency icon with an Opacity value (0 - 100) overlaying it.

Clicking the icon turns it editable, so the user can write an exact number, for example '50', and also unveils a small adjacent popup with a slider to adjust the value. Changes are directly reflected in the map.

I would position it immediately to the right of the (visibility) checkbox, as the two are closely related.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how I would see the opacity showing up. You can also go with something like adobe photoshop has for layer visibility and then that is a feature that appears only once. Meaning that your users will select the layer then somewhere at the top of the box you will have an opacity textbox with a slider attached to it.

If you want to introduce the transparency feature at a layer lever i craeted this little mockup for you.

[image]